# Is there any DOM event listeners to detect change in height of window?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I tried window.resize event listener, but it does not fulfil my needs. It detects change in width of window. I need to detect the change of browser window's height only.

I need something like

```
window.addEventListener("onHeightResizeOnly", 
() => {
  console.log(window.innerHeight);
});
```

Comment: What exactly are your “needs”? There’s most likely a better way of doing whatever you need listening for height changes for.

Comment: To do _what_? If it’s just some CSS change, then this can be done without JS. Do you need to distinguish a user opening the dev tools and a user simply resizing the window?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Example: User opens website and then open developer tools docked at bottom, in this case the innerHeight of window changes. I want to detect such change in height of window only.

Window.resize event listens for height and width both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the resize event and compare `window.innerHeight` to a previous value stored.

```js
let previousHeight = window.innerHeight
window.addEventListener("heightChange", (event) => {
  console.log(event.type, event.detail);
});
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  if (window.innerHeight > previousHeight) {
    // bigger
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("heightChange", {
      detail: { type: "larger", previousHeight, newHeight: window.innerHeight }
    }));
  } else if (window.innerHeight < previousHeight) {
    // smaller
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("heightChange", {
      detail: { type: "smaller", previousHeight, newHeight: window.innerHeight }
    }));
  } else {
    // height not changed
  }
  previousHeight = window.innerHeight;
}, { capture: true, passive: false });
```

(try the snippet in full page-style)

Comment: I want my code only to work when height is changed of window. The solution won't work unless window is resized, which means first width of browser needs to be changed.

Example: User open website and then open developer tools docked at bottom, in this case the innerHeight of window change. The solution will fail.

Comment: No it won't fail. Resize event also triggers if an attached window resizes the main window. `window.innerHeight` returns the height of the webview, not the browser window itself.

Comment: Yes but it listens for width and height both. I asked for height only. Isn't there any listeners. Your solution is correct but Window.resize already covers exactly what your code does.

Comment: There is no height only event. Due to the if conditions, it only does something on height changes. Define it on your own if you need one. You could use my example and dispatch a new Event on "bigger"/"smaller" or call your functions there.

Comment: Please edit your answer to create a new event to listen to height only.

Comment: I updated my answer, to show how to make use of CustomEvents.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be an event listener you can try a Resize Observer as explained [here](https://usefulangle.com/post/319/javascript-detect-element-resize):

```
const resize_ob = new ResizeObserver(function(entries) {
    // since we are observing only a single element, so we access the first element in entries array
    let rect = entries[0].contentRect;

    // current height
    let height = rect.height;
    console.log('Current Height : ' + height);
});

// start observing for resize
resize_ob.observe(document.querySelector("body"));
```